# How to push the information to send grid web api?

Tags: sendgrid

If i want to send some list to send grid web api. Any one can help how can we send the initial list to send grid?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you're looking to do.

If you want to use the **[SendGrid Marketing Email Tool](http://sendgrid.com/email-marketing)**, then you should use the [add list endpoint](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/lists.html#-add) to create your list. To then add recipients to the list, use the [add recipient endpoint](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/recipients.html#-add).

However, if you're looking to use the "**[Web API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/index.html)**", the best way to push emails to a list is through the [`x-smptapi`](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html) parameter found on the [send mail endpoint](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html). *Despite its name, [the SMTP API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html) may be used over both SMTP and Web transport*. The [`to`](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html#-The-XSMTPAPI-Header) parameter will then allow you to distribute a single email to your list.